# MATLAB. How can I sum all the rows of the first column when on the second column the rows have the same value?

Tags: matlab

On MATLAB. Let's assume I have a matrix A(i,j). In this case i=5 and j=4. I want to sum all the rows of the first column when, on the second column, the rows have the same value. Taking a matrix like:

```
4000    54571
4000    54571
4000    54572
4000    54573
4000    54574
```

I would like to write a code that returns:

```
8000    54571
4000    54572
4000    54573
4000    54574
```

Do you have an Idea on how to do that?

thank you very much,

Comment: Can you use this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps with `unique` and `accumarray`

```
octave:1> X=[4000    54571
> 4000    54571
> 4000    54572
> 4000    54573
> 4000    54574
> ]
X =

    4000   54571
    4000   54571
    4000   54572
    4000   54573
    4000   54574

octave:2> [keys,~,values] = unique(X(:,2));
octave:3> [accumarray(values,X(:,1)), keys]
ans =

    8000   54571
    4000   54572
    4000   54573
    4000   54574
```